# SelectField renders unicode syntax

Tags: forms, unicode, flask-wtforms

When dynamically creating choices for SelectField in WTForms, I get (u'Choice',) rendered in the dropdown list.
I suspect its something to do with unicode, but no idea how to get the correct string.

for example

```
form.group_id_name.choices = [(row, row) for row in db.session.query(entry.group_id_name).distinct()]
```

In my forms I have

```
 group_id_name = SelectField('group_id_name')
```

I would like it to render

```
<select id="group_id_name" name="group_id_name"><option value="Choice1">Choice1</option><option value="Choice2">Choice2</option></select>
```

Instead I get

```
<select id="group_id_name" name="group_id_name"><option value="(u'Choice1',)">(u'Choice1',)</option><option value="(u'Choice2',)">(u'Choice2',)</option></select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not anything to do with Unicode.

`query()` returns a sequence of column values for each row. For a query with only one column in it you get a length-1-tuple.

When you implicitly convert a tuple to a string as part of the template you get the Python code representation of the tuple, which looks like `(somevalue,)`.

You want to include the string value of the column itself in the template, so you should access the first element of the sequence, eg:

```
form.group_id_name.choices = [(row[0], row[0]) for row in db.session.query(entry.group_id_name).distinct()]
```

or using unpacking assignment:

```
form.group_id_name.choices = [(name, name) for (name,) in db.session.query(entry.group_id_name).distinct()]
```

Comment: Thank you, thats exactly it. I am new to python and the whole lists, tuples, dictionaries, and combinations thereof, is a tad confusing. Extremely powerful, but confusing.