# Select looks weird in html using form

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I'm currently programming a little application for school purposes, but I've found a little problem: using wtf.form to create a SelectField in the html, the results are not what I wanted. It shows for all the options" (u'Exemple') ", I'd rather that it just be "Exemple".
I thought that the problem comes from the method I used to enlist a column from a database but then I'd have no idea to change method and use one more useful.
let me post the form I'm talking about:

```
class AddEventForm(FlaskForm):
      list_of_park = Parks.query.with_entities(Parks.name_parks)
      name_park = SelectField('Name of the park:', choices=list_of_park)
      calendar = StringField('Date:', validators=[DataRequired()])
      time = StringField('Time:', validators=[DataRequired()])
      name = StringField('Name of the event:', validators=[DataRequired()])
      submit = SubmitField('Add a new Event')
```

Parks is the database, and I need to use just that column moreover, I've just figured out that this method doesn't eliminate the duplicates.

Thanks for any answer!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SelectField renders unicode syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30120867/selectfield-renders-unicode-syntax)

Comment: Yeah, got it! Thanks!!